# using parenthesis inside an assigment in a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, operators

i had a very bad time trying to find a bug in the my code turned out to be that i missed a pair of parenthesis inside a while loop that i still don't know it's significance.

so why these lines are different from each other:

```
 while (( (bytes_read = read(inputFILE, buffer, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0))
 while (( bytes_read = read(inputFILE, buffer, BUFF_SIZE) > 0))
```

the second line was the bug that resulted that when i try to write buffer to a file only one character was written no matter what. What change did this extra pair of parenthesis does

The Whole Loop with correct line is:

```
while (( (bytes_read = read(inputFILE, buffer, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)){
        bytes_write = write(outputFILE, buffer, bytes_read);
        if (bytes_write != bytes_read)
            fatal("Couldnt write data to %s", argv[2]);
```

Comment: Both of those lines of code have an extra set of parentheses. That extra set should be deleted, because the extra set of parentheses disables the checking that the compiler does to detect this kind of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is:

```
(something = something_else) > 0
```

(assign `something_else` to `something`, then check if it's greater than zero)

compared to:

```
something = something_else > 0
```

which is the same as

```
something = (something_else > 0)
```

(check if `something_else` is greater than 0, then assign that to `something`).

The first one stores the actual value of `something_else` in the variable `something`. The second one only stores 1 or 0 depending on whether it was greater than 0 or not.

Answer (score 4):

The relational operator `>` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the second line of code parses as:

```
while (( bytes_read = (read(inputFILE, buffer, BUFF_SIZE) > 0)) )
```

In other words, the return value of `read` is compared against 0, then that result (either 0 or 1) is assigned to `bytes_read`.